# Getting values out of Node core vm module

Tags: node.js

How do you get the value in the context of a vm in node.

If I create a context and run a script in it do I use `util.inspect([[context]])`?

And if I do does it come back serialized?

for some reason when I `util.inspect("null")` it comes back with 
`'\'null'\'`

Does any one know why, and also what the best way to get values out of a context run in nodes vm module?

I've also done some micro benchmarks and it seems that creating a new context is much slower than running it in `thisContext`. Also when I get rid of the timeout its seem like it run **much** faster.

So I would like to use this context without having to use globals to not cause leakage, and also try to speed up the performance of this.

The context of this code is that I'm trying to sandbox a catastrophic regex.

```js
global.mapperContext = {
  result: false
};

const scriptString = `
  global.mapperContext.result = true;

  if ("${string}".match(${regex})) {
    global.mapperContext.result = false;
  }
`;

const vmScript = new vm.script(scriptString);

try {
  vmScript.runInThisContext({ timeout: 1000 });
} catch (e) {
  // Do something with error
}

// This works but I dont like attaching things to the global object.
// I could cause memory leaks...
console.log(global.mapperContext);
```

```js
const mapperContext = { result };

const scriptString = `
(function IIFE() {

  result = true;

  if ("${string}".match(${regex})) {
    result = false;
  }

})()
`;

const sandbox = vm.createContext(mapperContext);
const script = new vm.script(scriptString);

script.runInContext(script, sandbox, {timeout: 1000});

// This result is serialized and is hard to parse.
util.inspect(sandbox.result);
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple (code) example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @mscdex I've updated the ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct, but your [`script.runInContext()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/vm.html#vm_script_runinnewcontext_sandbox_options) should instead look like this:

```
script.runInContext(sandbox, {timeout: 1000});
```

With that change, you should see `sandbox.result` as a boolean.

As far as performance goes, you should be able to reuse the `sandbox` variables across multiple calls to `script.runInContext()`, so that will help some.

Something else you might try is to create a generic script that you can reuse for any string and regex values by passing them to the same script instead of creating new scripts for each set of values. For example:

```
const vm = require('vm');
const mapperContext = { result: false, string: 'bar', regex: /baa/ };

const scriptString = `
(function IIFE() {

  result = true;

  if (regex.test(string)) {
    result = false;
  }

})()
`;

// Only perform these two calls once ...
const sandbox = vm.createContext(mapperContext);
const script = new vm.Script(scriptString);

// ... and then run the script as many times as needed ...
script.runInContext(sandbox, {timeout: 1000});
console.dir(sandbox.result);

// ...

mapperContext.string = 'foo';
mapperContext.regex = /foo/;
script.runInContext(sandbox, {timeout: 1000});
console.dir(sandbox.result);

// ...
```

One twist you may also consider is to simply return a boolean instead of setting a global (`result`) inside the function, that way the return value is available as the return value of `script.runInContext()`. For example:

```
const vm = require('vm');
const mapperContext = { string: 'bar', regex: /baa/ };
const scriptString = 'regex.test(string);';
const sandbox = vm.createContext(mapperContext);
const script = new vm.Script(scriptString);
var ret;

ret = script.runInContext(sandbox, {timeout: 1000});
console.dir(ret);

// ...

mapperContext.string = 'foo';
mapperContext.regex = /foo/;
ret = script.runInContext(sandbox, {timeout: 1000});
console.dir(ret);

// ...
```

Lastly, of course you will want to make sure to wrap your calls to `script.runInContext()` in a try-catch block in case there is a timeout. For performance (pre-node v7.0.0), you will want to isolate this try-catch in a separate function since before node v7, V8 would permanently deoptimize the entire function containing the try-catch (or try-finally):

```
const vm = require('vm');

function tryRun(string, regex, timeout) {
  var ctx = tryRun.ctx;
  var sandbox = tryRun.sandbox;
  var script = tryRun.script;
  if (!ctx) {
    ctx = tryRun.ctx = { string: string, regex: regex };
    sandbox = tryRun.sandbox = vm.createContext(ctx);
    script = tryRun.script = new vm.Script('regex.test(string)');
  } else {
    ctx.string = string;
    ctx.regex = regex;
  }
  timeout = timeout || 1000;
  try {
    return script.runInContext(sandbox, {timeout});
  } catch (ex) {
    return ex;
  }
}

console.dir(tryRun('bar', /baa/));

// ...

console.dir(tryRun('foo', /foo/));

// ...

// Example of timeout
console.dir(tryRun('xxxx'.repeat(100), /(x+x+)+y/));

// ...
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'll give those a shot!